# Locate element with special tagname and attribute - Protractor

Tags: selenium, automation, protractor

I'm having trouble locating this element (and some other similar elements) using XPath (or other locators), I tried to use the (path) as a tag name but I couldn't, I want to locate the (stroke="#929292") - which is the color of the block - to use in my automation test scenario.

```html
<svg style="width: 100%; height: 100%; display: block; min-width: 5105px; min-height: 1890px; position: absolute; background-image: none;"><g><g></g><g><g transform="translate(0.5,0.5)" style="visibility: visible; cursor: move;"><rect x="2441.25" y="880.5" width="166.5" height="129" rx="12.9" ry="12.9" fill="#fff" stroke="#929292" pointer-events="all"></rect></g><g style="visibility: visible; cursor: move;"><image x="2448.75" y="891.75" width="150" height="41.25" xlink:href="https://app.yonohub.com/editor/block-icon/245b8fa25c4047cf9600349aacd0de61.svg"></image></g><g style="cursor: move;"><g transform="translate(2481,941)scale(0.75)"><foreignObject style="overflow:visible;" pointer-events="all" width="114" height="22"><div style="display: inline-block; font-size: 20px; font-family: Lato; color: rgb(98, 96, 120); line-height: 1.2; vertical-align: top; width: 116px; white-space: normal; overflow-wrap: normal; font-weight: bold; text-align: center;"><div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="display:inline-block;text-align:inherit;text-decoration:inherit;background-color:;">Video Player</div></div></foreignObject></g></g><g transform="translate(0.5,0.5)" style="visibility: visible; cursor: move;"><path d="M 2441.25 991.66 L 2441.25 983.25 L 2607.75 983.25 L 2607.75 991.66 Q 2607.75 1008.75 2594.43 1008.75 L 2454.57 1008.75 Q 2441.25 1008.75 2441.25 991.66 L 2441.25 991.66 Z" fill="#929292" stroke="#929292" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="all"></path></g><g transform="translate(0.5,0.5)" style="visibility: visible;"><rect x="2463.75" y="983.25" width="30" height="25.5" fill="transparent" stroke="none" pointer-events="all"></rect></g><g style=""><g transform="translate(2468,990)scale(0.75)"><foreignObject style="overflow:visible;" pointer-events="all" width="29" height="17"><div style="display:inline-block;font-size:16px;font-family:Lato;color:#777;line-height:1.2;vertical-align:top;white-space:nowrap;text-align:center;"><div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="display:inline-block;text-align:inherit;text-decoration:inherit;"><span class="icon-gpu"></span></div></div></foreignObject></g></g><g transform="translate(0.5,0.5)" style="visibility: visible;"><rect x="2493.75" y="983.25" width="30" height="25.5" fill="transparent" stroke="none" pointer-events="all"></rect></g><g style=""><g transform="translate(2502,990)scale(0.75)"><foreignObject style="overflow:visible;" pointer-events="all" width="18" height="17"><div style="display:inline-block;font-size:16px;font-family:Lato;color:#777;line-height:1.2;vertical-align:top;white-space:nowrap;text-align:center;"><div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="display:inline-block;text-align:inherit;text-decoration:inherit;"><span class="icon-training"></span></div></div></foreignObject></g></g><g transform="translate(0.5,0.5)" style="visibility: visible;"><rect x="2523.75" y="983.25" width="30" height="25.5" fill="transparent" stroke="none" pointer-events="all"></rect></g><g style=""><g transform="translate(2532,990)scale(0.75)"><foreignObject style="overflow:visible;" pointer-events="all" width="19" height="17"><div style="display:inline-block;font-size:16px;font-family:Lato;color:#777;line-height:1.2;vertical-align:top;white-space:nowrap;text-align:center;"><div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="display:inline-block;text-align:inherit;text-decoration:inherit;"><span class="icon-error"></span></div></div></foreignObject></g></g><g transform="translate(0.5,0.5)" style="visibility: visible;"><rect x="2553.75" y="983.25" width="30" height="25.5" fill="transparent" stroke="none" pointer-events="all"></rect></g><g style=""><g transform="translate(2559,990)scale(0.75)"><foreignObject style="overflow:visible;" pointer-events="all" width="25" height="17"><div style="display:inline-block;font-size:16px;font-family:Lato;color:#777;line-height:1.2;vertical-align:top;white-space:nowrap;text-align:center;"><div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="display:inline-block;text-align:inherit;text-decoration:inherit;"><span class="icon-duplication"></span></div></div></foreignObject></g></g><g style="visibility: visible; cursor: move;"><rect x="2456.25" y="963" width="135" height="15" rx="2.25" ry="2.25" fill="none" stroke="white" stroke-width="9.5" pointer-events="stroke" visibility="hidden"></rect><rect x="2456.25" y="963" width="135" height="15" rx="2.25" ry="2.25" fill="none" stroke="#70707030" stroke-width="1.5" pointer-events="all"></rect></g><g style="cursor: move;"><g fill="#000000" font-family="Lato" text-anchor="middle" font-size="9px"><text x="2523.75" y="973.5">Yonohub Team</text></g></g><g transform="translate(0.5,0.5)" style="visibility: visible;"><rect x="2605.25" y="934.68" width="4.5" height="4.5" rx="2.25" ry="2.25" fill="#ffffff" stroke="#2d2a53" pointer-events="all"></rect></g><g transform="translate(0.5,0.5)" style="visibility: visible; cursor: move;"><rect x="2448.75" y="850.5" width="150" height="37.5" fill="transparent" stroke="none" pointer-events="all"></rect></g><g transform="translate(0.5,0.5)" style="visibility: visible; cursor: move;"><rect x="2441.25" y="1009.5" width="166.5" height="129" rx="12.9" ry="12.9" fill="#fff" stroke="#929292" pointer-events="all"></rect></g><g transform="translate(0.5,0.5)" style="visibility: visible; cursor: move;"><rect x="2448.75" y="1020.75" width="150" height="15" rx="1.5" ry="1.5" fill="#ffffff" stroke="none" pointer-events="all"></rect></g><g style="cursor: move;"><g transform="translate(2472,1044)scale(0.75)"><foreignObject style="overflow:visible;" pointer-events="all" width="138" height="22"><div style="display: inline-block; font-size: 20px; font-family: Lato; color: rgb(98, 96, 120); line-height: 1.2; vertical-align: top; width: 138px; white-space: normal; overflow-wrap: normal; font-weight: bold; text-align: center;"><div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="display:inline-block;text-align:inherit;text-decoration:inherit;background-color:;">Edge Detection</div></div></foreignObject></g></g><g transform="translate(0.5,0.5)" style="visibility: visible; cursor: move;"><path d="M 2441.25 1120.66 L 2441.25 1112.25 L 2607.75 1112.25 L 2607.75 1120.66 Q 2607.75 1137.75 2594.43 1137.75 L 2454.57 1137.75 Q 2441.25 1137.75 2441.25 1120.66 L 2441.25 1120.66 Z" fill="#929292" stroke="#929292" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="all"></path></g><g transform="translate(0.5,0.5)" style="visibility: visible;"><rect x="2463.75" y="1112.25" width="30" height="25.5" fill="transparent" stroke="none" pointer-events="all"></rect></g><g style=""><g transform="translate(2468,1119)scale(0.75)"><foreignObject style="overflow:visible;" pointer-events="all" width="29" height="17"><div style="display:inline-block;font-size:16px;font-family:Lato;color:#777;line-height:1.2;vertical-align:top;white-space:nowrap;text-align:center;"><div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="display:inline-block;text-align:inherit;text-decoration:inherit;"><span class="icon-gpu"></span></div></div></foreignObject></g></g><g transform="translate(0.5,0.5)" style="visibility: visible;"><rect x="2493.75" y="1112.25" width="30" height="25.5" fill="transparent" stroke="none" pointer-events="all"></rect></g><g style=""><g transform="translate(2502,1119)scale(0.75)"><foreignObject style="overflow:visible;" pointer-events="all" width="18" height="17"><div style="display:inline-block;font-size:16px;font-family:Lato;color:#777;line-height:1.2;vertical-align:top;white-space:nowrap;text-align:center;"><div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="display:inline-block;text-align:inherit;text-decoration:inherit;"><span class="icon-training"></span></div></div></foreignObject></g></g><g transform="translate(0.5,0.5)" style="visibility: visible;"><rect x="2523.75" y="1112.25" width="30" height="25.5" fill="transparent" stroke="none" pointer-events="all"></rect></g><g style=""><g transform="translate(2532,1119)scale(0.75)"><foreignObject style="overflow:visible;" pointer-events="all" width="19" height="17"><div style="display:inline-block;font-size:16px;font-family:Lato;color:#777;line-height:1.2;vertical-align:top;white-space:nowrap;text-align:center;"><div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="display:inline-block;text-align:inherit;text-decoration:inherit;"><span class="icon-error"></span></div></div></foreignObject></g></g><g transform="translate(0.5,0.5)" style="visibility: visible;"><rect x="2553.75" y="1112.25" width="30" height="25.5" fill="transparent" stroke="none" pointer-events="all"></rect></g><g style=""><g transform="translate(2559,1119)scale(0.75)"><foreignObject style="overflow:visible;" pointer-events="all" width="25" height="17"><div style="display:inline-block;font-size:16px;font-family:Lato;color:#777;line-height:1.2;vertical-align:top;white-space:nowrap;text-align:center;"><div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="display:inline-block;text-align:inherit;text-decoration:inherit;"><span class="icon-duplication"></span></div></div></foreignObject></g></g><g style="visibility: visible; cursor: move;"><rect x="2456.25" y="1092" width="135" height="15" rx="2.25" ry="2.25" fill="none" stroke="white" stroke-width="9.5" pointer-events="stroke" visibility="hidden"></rect><rect x="2456.25" y="1092" width="135" height="15" rx="2.25" ry="2.25" fill="none" stroke="#70707030" stroke-width="1.5" pointer-events="all"></rect></g><g style="cursor: move;"><g fill="#000000" font-family="Lato" text-anchor="middle" font-size="9px"><text x="2523.75" y="1102.5">Yonohub Team</text></g></g><g transform="translate(0.5,0.5)" style="visibility: visible;"><rect x="2438.75" y="1063.68" width="4.5" height="4.5" rx="2.25" ry="2.25" fill="#ffffff" stroke="#2d2a53" pointer-events="all"></rect></g><g transform="translate(0.5,0.5)" style="visibility: visible;"><rect x="2605.25" y="1063.68" width="4.5" height="4.5" rx="2.25" ry="2.25" fill="#ffffff" stroke="#2d2a53" pointer-events="all"></rect></g><g transform="translate(0.5,0.5)" style="visibility: visible; cursor: move;"><rect x="2448.75" y="979.5" width="150" height="37.5" fill="transparent" stroke="none" pointer-events="all"></rect></g><g transform="translate(0.5,0.5)" style="visibility: visible; cursor: move;"><rect x="2441.25" y="1138.5" width="166.5" height="129" rx="12.9" ry="12.9" fill="#fff" stroke="#929292" pointer-events="all"></rect></g><g style="visibility: visible; cursor: move;"><image x="2448.75" y="1149.75" width="150" height="41.25" xlink:href="https://app.yonohub.com/editor/block-icon/71581b985bfb477782fcf2cf53863573.svg"></image></g><g style="cursor: move;"><g transform="translate(2478,1199)scale(0.75)"><foreignObject style="overflow:visible;" pointer-events="all" width="122" height="22"><div style="display: inline-block; font-size: 20px; font-family: Lato; color: rgb(98, 96, 120); line-height: 1.2; vertical-align: top; width: 122px; white-space: normal; overflow-wrap: normal; font-weight: bold; text-align: center;"><div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="display:inline-block;text-align:inherit;text-decoration:inherit;background-color:;">Video Viewer</div></div></foreignObject></g></g><g transform="translate(0.5,0.5)" style="visibility: visible; cursor: move;"><path d="M 2441.25 1249.66 L 2441.25 1241.25 L 2607.75 1241.25 L 2607.75 1249.66 Q 2607.75 1266.75 2594.43 1266.75 L 2454.57 1266.75 Q 2441.25 1266.75 2441.25 1249.66 L 2441.25 1249.66 Z" fill="#929292" stroke="#929292" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="all"></path></g><g transform="translate(0.5,0.5)" style="visibility: visible; cursor: move;"><rect x="2463.75" y="1241.25" width="30" height="25.5" fill="transparent" stroke="none" pointer-events="all"></rect></g><g style="cursor: move;"><g transform="translate(2468,1248)scale(0.75)"><foreignObject style="overflow:visible;" pointer-events="all" width="29" height="17"><div style="display:inline-block;font-size:16px;font-family:Lato;color:#777;line-height:1.2;vertical-align:top;white-space:nowrap;text-align:center;"><div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="display:inline-block;text-align:inherit;text-decoration:inherit;"><span class="icon-gpu"></span></div></div></foreignObject></g></g><g transform="translate(0.5,0.5)" style="visibility: visible;"><rect x="2493.75" y="1241.25" width="30" height="25.5" fill="transparent" stroke="none" pointer-events="all"></rect></g><g style=""><g transform="translate(2502,1248)scale(0.75)"><foreignObject style="overflow:visible;" pointer-events="all" width="18" height="17"><div style="display:inline-block;font-size:16px;font-family:Lato;color:#777;line-height:1.2;vertical-align:top;white-space:nowrap;text-align:center;"><div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="display:inline-block;text-align:inherit;text-decoration:inherit;"><span class="icon-training"></span></div></div></foreignObject></g></g><g transform="translate(0.5,0.5)" style="visibility: visible;"><rect x="2523.75" y="1241.25" width="30" height="25.5" fill="transparent" stroke="none" pointer-events="all"></rect></g><g style=""><g transform="translate(2532,1248)scale(0.75)"><foreignObject style="overflow:visible;" pointer-events="all" width="19" height="17"><div style="display:inline-block;font-size:16px;font-family:Lato;color:#777;line-height:1.2;vertical-align:top;white-space:nowrap;text-align:center;"><div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="display:inline-block;text-align:inherit;text-decoration:inherit;"><span class="icon-error"></span></div></div></foreignObject></g></g><g transform="translate(0.5,0.5)" style="visibility: visible; cursor: move;"><rect x="2553.75" y="1241.25" width="30" height="25.5" fill="transparent" stroke="none" pointer-events="all"></rect></g><g style="cursor: move;"><g transform="translate(2559,1248)scale(0.75)"><foreignObject style="overflow:visible;" pointer-events="all" width="25" height="17"><div style="display:inline-block;font-size:16px;font-family:Lato;color:#777;line-height:1.2;vertical-align:top;white-space:nowrap;text-align:center;"><div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="display:inline-block;text-align:inherit;text-decoration:inherit;"><span class="icon-duplication"></span></div></div></foreignObject></g></g><g style="visibility: visible; cursor: move;"><rect x="2456.25" y="1221" width="135" height="15" rx="2.25" ry="2.25" fill="none" stroke="white" stroke-width="9.5" pointer-events="stroke" visibility="hidden"></rect><rect x="2456.25" y="1221" width="135" height="15" rx="2.25" ry="2.25" fill="none" stroke="#70707030" stroke-width="1.5" pointer-events="all"></rect></g><g style="cursor: move;"><g fill="#000000" font-family="Lato" text-anchor="middle" font-size="9px"><text x="2523.75" y="1231.5">Yonohub Team</text></g></g><g transform="translate(0.5,0.5)" style="visibility: visible;"><rect x="2438.75" y="1192.68" width="4.5" height="4.5" rx="2.25" ry="2.25" fill="#ffffff" stroke="#2d2a53" pointer-events="all"></rect></g><g transform="translate(0.5,0.5)" style="visibility: visible; cursor: move;"><rect x="2448.75" y="1108.5" width="150" height="37.5" fill="transparent" stroke="none" pointer-events="all"></rect></g><g style="visibility: visible; cursor: move;" class=""><path d="M 2605.25 936.93 L 2524 936.93 L 2524 1065.93 L 2452.52 1065.93" fill="none" stroke="white" stroke-width="10.25" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="stroke" visibility="hidden"></path><path d="M 2605.25 936.93 L 2524 936.93 L 2524 1065.93 L 2452.52 1065.93" fill="none" stroke="#838383" stroke-width="2.25" stroke-miterlimit="10"></path><path d="M 2445.77 1065.93 L 2452.52 1063.68 L 2452.52 1068.18 Z" fill="#838383" stroke="#838383" stroke-width="2.25" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="all"></path></g><g style="visibility: visible; cursor: move;" class=""><path d="M 2605.25 1065.93 L 2524 1065.93 L 2524 1194.93 L 2452.52 1194.93" fill="none" stroke="white" stroke-width="10.25" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="stroke" visibility="hidden"></path><path d="M 2605.25 1065.93 L 2524 1065.93 L 2524 1194.93 L 2452.52 1194.93" fill="none" stroke="#838383" stroke-width="2.25" stroke-miterlimit="10"></path><path d="M 2445.77 1194.93 L 2452.52 1192.68 L 2452.52 1197.18 Z" fill="#838383" stroke="#838383" stroke-width="2.25" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="all"></path></g></g><g><g style="cursor: pointer; visibility: hidden;"></g><g style="cursor: pointer; visibility: visible;"><image x="2456.25" y="888" width="12" height="12" xlink:href="https://app.yonohub.com/editor/images/settings.svg" preserveAspectRatio="none"></image></g><g style="cursor: pointer; visibility: visible;"><image x="2520" y="985.5" width="37.5" height="22.5" xlink:href="https://app.yonohub.com/editor/images/empty.svg" preserveAspectRatio="none"></image></g><g style="cursor: pointer;"></g><g style="cursor: pointer;"></g><g style="cursor: pointer;"></g><g style="cursor: pointer;"></g><g style="cursor: pointer;"></g><g style="cursor: pointer;"></g><g style="cursor: pointer;"></g><g style="cursor: pointer;"></g><g style="cursor: pointer;"></g><g style="cursor: pointer;"></g><g style="cursor: pointer;"></g><g style="cursor: pointer;"></g><g style="cursor: pointer;"></g><g style="cursor: pointer;"></g><g style="cursor: pointer;"></g><g style="cursor: pointer;"></g><g style="cursor: pointer;"></g><g style="cursor: pointer;"></g><g style="cursor: pointer;"></g><g style="cursor: pointer;"></g><g style="cursor: pointer;"></g><g style="cursor: pointer;"></g><g style="cursor: pointer;"></g><g style="cursor: pointer;"></g><g style="cursor: pointer;"></g><g style="cursor: pointer;"></g><g style="cursor: pointer;"></g><g style="cursor: pointer;"></g><g style="cursor: pointer;"></g><g style="cursor: pointer;"></g><g style="cursor: pointer;"></g><g style="cursor: pointer;"></g><g style="cursor: pointer;"></g><g style="cursor: pointer;"></g><g style="cursor: pointer;"></g><g style="cursor: pointer;"></g><g style="cursor: pointer;"></g><g style="cursor: pointer; visibility: hidden;"></g><g style="cursor: pointer; visibility: visible;"><image x="2456.25" y="1017" width="12" height="12" xlink:href="https://app.yonohub.com/editor/images/settings.svg" preserveAspectRatio="none"></image></g><g style="cursor: pointer; visibility: visible;"><image x="2520" y="1114.5" width="37.5" height="22.5" xlink:href="https://app.yonohub.com/editor/images/empty.svg" preserveAspectRatio="none"></image></g><g style="cursor: pointer;"></g><g style="cursor: pointer;"></g><g style="cursor: pointer;"></g><g style="cursor: pointer;"></g><g style="cursor: pointer;"></g><g style="cursor: pointer;"></g><g style="cursor: pointer;"></g><g style="cursor: pointer;"></g><g style="cursor: pointer;"></g><g style="cursor: pointer;"></g><g style="cursor: pointer;"></g><g style="cursor: pointer;"></g><g style="cursor: pointer;"></g><g style="cursor: pointer;"></g><g style="cursor: pointer;"></g><g style="cursor: pointer;"></g><g style="cursor: pointer;"></g><g style="cursor: pointer;"></g><g style="cursor: pointer;"></g><g style="cursor: pointer;"></g><g style="cursor: pointer;"></g><g style="cursor: pointer;"></g><g style="cursor: pointer;"></g><g style="cursor: pointer;"></g><g style="cursor: pointer;"></g><g style="cursor: pointer;"></g><g style="cursor: pointer;"></g><g style="cursor: pointer;"></g><g style="cursor: pointer;"></g><g style="cursor: pointer;"></g><g style="cursor: pointer;"></g><g style="cursor: pointer;"></g><g style="cursor: pointer;"></g><g style="cursor: pointer;"></g><g style="cursor: pointer;"></g><g style="cursor: pointer;"></g><g style="cursor: pointer;"></g><g style="cursor: pointer;"></g><g style="cursor: pointer;"></g><g style="cursor: pointer;"></g><g style="cursor: pointer;"></g><g style="cursor: pointer; visibility: hidden;"></g><g style="cursor: pointer; visibility: visible;"><image x="2456.25" y="1146" width="12" height="12" xlink:href="https://app.yonohub.com/editor/images/settings.svg" preserveAspectRatio="none"></image></g><g style="cursor: pointer; visibility: visible;"><image x="2520" y="1243.5" width="37.5" height="22.5" xlink:href="https://app.yonohub.com/editor/images/empty.svg" preserveAspectRatio="none"></image></g><g style="cursor: pointer;"></g><g style="cursor: pointer;"></g><g style="cursor: pointer;"></g><g style="cursor: pointer;"></g><g style="cursor: pointer;"></g><g style="cursor: pointer;"></g><g style="cursor: pointer;"></g><g style="cursor: pointer;"></g><g style="cursor: pointer;"></g><g style="cursor: pointer;"></g><g style="cursor: pointer;"></g><g style="cursor: pointer;"></g><g style="cursor: pointer;"></g><g style="cursor: pointer;"></g><g style="cursor: pointer;"></g><g style="cursor: pointer;"></g><g style="cursor: pointer;"></g><g style="cursor: pointer;"></g><g style="cursor: pointer;"></g><g style="cursor: pointer;"></g><g style="cursor: pointer;"></g><g style="cursor: pointer;"></g><g style="cursor: pointer;"></g><g style="cursor: pointer;"></g><g style="cursor: pointer;"></g><g style="cursor: pointer;"></g><g style="cursor: pointer;"></g><g style="cursor: pointer;"></g><g style="cursor: pointer;"></g><g style="cursor: pointer;"></g><g style="cursor: pointer;"></g><g style="cursor: pointer;"></g><g style="cursor: pointer;"></g><g style="cursor: pointer;"></g><g style="cursor: pointer;"></g><g style="cursor: pointer;"></g><g style="cursor: pointer;"></g></g><g></g></g></svg>
```

Comment: <g transform="translate(0.5,0.5)" style="visibility: visible; cursor: move;"><path d="M 1820.25 624.16 L 1820.25 615.75 L 1986.75 615.75 L 1986.75 624.16 Q 1986.75 641.25 1973.43 641.25 L 1833.57 641.25 Q 1820.25 641.25 1820.25 624.16 L 1820.25 624.16 Z" fill="#929292" stroke="#929292" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="all"></path></g>

Comment: What do you mean by saying ' want to locate the (stroke="#929292") - which is the color of the block'?  ElementFinder simply represents a single element on your page. Are you saying you want to validate a style property of the element?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying interact with [SVG](https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/svg_path.asp) element.In order access that element you need to use following xpath.

Try below xpath:

```
//*[name()='g']/*[@stroke='#929292']
```

OR

```
//*[local-name()='g']/path[@stroke='#929292']
```

OR

```
//*[name()='g']/path[@stroke='#929292']
```

OR

```
//*[local-name()='g']/*[@stroke='#929292']
```

Comment: it worked but still locating to many elements, what can I do to locate this specific element?

Comment: @kiko you need to provide more relevant HTML with parent tag.so that can check how to make this unique.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use css selector:

`const neededEleme = $('g [stroke="#929292"]')`